# Generate minified public javascript in Nuxt.js/Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vite, nitro

We have a relatively boilerplate Nuxt.js application, deployed with the "firebase" preset of Nitro to Firebase hosting.

In addition to the JavaScript that makes up the application itself, we have a file in public/embed.js that is intended to be referenced by third parties (it is used to facilitate embedding of a widget on their website).

I would like the `embed.js` file to be tersed/minified during the build process, so that anyone that requests it receives a minified version. Currently, the file seems to be copied from `public/embed.js` to the `.output/public` directory without modification.

Can this be done with configuration options, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a script to minify your file and run it along with your build script like this:

```json
// package.json
{
  "scripts": {
    "minify-embed": "uglifyjs public/embed.js",
    "build": "yarn minify-embed && yarn build:client && yarn build:server",
  }
}
```

But if your `embed.js` is rarely changed, you just need to manually minify it and then put it in the `public` folder

Comment: I was hoping there was some kind of nuxt/vite config that would allow me to do this declaratively as part of then normal build. That said, just running an extra step during build to do the minify is a pretty simple solution for this basic use case.